# nginx connection refused after config

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I was setting up nginx on my aws ubuntu instance. At first every time went well, but after I config nginx and try to connect django, I can't even see the welcome page from either public ip nor the localhost(which was able to access from both sides). The nginx status command shows nginx is running.

Here's my nginx config:

```
/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com

server{

    charset utf-8;
    listen 80;
    server_name my_aws_ip;

    location /static{
        alias my_django_static_path;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://unix:tmp/mysite.socket;
    }
}
```

And I made a link to /nginx/sites-enabled/

It appears that every time I restarted nginx, I will be able to see the welcome page. However, after that, nginx refuses connections.

I didn't change anything in nginx.conf. Do I need to?

Comment: Use `nginx -t` to test the configuration file. You are missing a `;` after `charset utf-8`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

`server_name` should be your domain name, IP address should be specified as part of the `listen` directive

`proxy_pass http://unix:tmp/mysite.socket;`

Not sure where you are hoping this will end up, but you need to decide if you are sending it via http or to a socket. Not both. Having said that if it's for django then it's not `proxy_pass` you want at all

I'm guessing you mean:

`uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/mysite.socket;`

You'll also need to include [these](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/uwsgi_params) somewhere in your config